# Initializing Lists to Avoid Potential Errors

Tags: list, flutter, dart

This function

```
List<int> _calculateTrips() {
    List<int> trips = [];
    trips = List.generate(
      30,
      (index) {
        var counter = 0;
        var aDay = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: index));
        for (var aWalk in walks) {
          if ((aDay.month == aWalk.month) && (aDay.day == aWalk.day)) {
            counter++;
          }
        }
        trips.add(counter);
      },
    );
    return trips;
  }
```

creates the error `The body might complete normally, causing null to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.` I'm struggling a bit to understand the message because (a) I thought I initialized the list at the beginning of the function and (b) I thought I had a return statement at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the function you pass to `List.generate()`. It expects a `E Function(int)`, where `E` is the type of the element, for example:

```dart
final evenNumbers = List.generate(10, (index) {
  return index * 2;
});
```

Your issue comes from `trips.add(counter)`:

```dart
List<int> trips = [];
trips = List.generate(30, (index) {
  final trip = calculateTrip(index);
  trips.add(trip);
})
```

The inner function needs to be an `int Function(int)` (i.e. a function that takes an `int`, and returns an `int`), because your list is a `List<int>`.

However, your inner function never returns anything.

Simply replace `trips.add(counter);` with `return counter;` and it should solve this error. You may also want to refactor your function a little:

```dart
List<int> _calculateTrips() => List.generate(30, (index {
  var counter = 0;
  var aDay = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: index));
  for (var aWalk in walks) {
    if ((aDay.month == aWalk.month) && (aDay.day == aWalk.day)) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
});
```